# Sound doesn't stop when screen off in Nexus 6 with Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lifecycle

I am developing an app and I found an interesting stuff.

My device is Nexus 6 with L. This problem also appears in another Nexus 6 with L and my friend's Samsung S4 with L. I don't have many devices, thus can't collect more samples. Most phones don't seem to have this problem.

For most of apps, if the app has audio, it should be paused (activity, fragment, and sound) when the screen went off.

For my phone (nexus 6 with L), however, the sound didn't go off until a period of time. And I found out the length of the period can be adjust in "Automatic Lock" in secure setting. If you set the automatic lock as 30 seconds after screen off, the music will be continued for 30 seconds after the screen is off.

I wonder wether this is an Android bug? It seems like the onPause method is called when the phone is locked, not when the screen is off. Most phones seem don't have this problem, the onPause is called immediately when the screen off.

From Fragment lifecycle, the fragment should be entering Paused state when screen off. I think it's bit weird in some phone (nexus 6 with L)
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

My fix is I register broadcast receiver listening to Screen On and Off. When the screen went off, it called onPause. It's a bit hacky but it did fix problem. I wonder any another experiences the same problem?

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Set the sleep time to 15s (Display Setting)
2. Set the automatic lock to 30s (Secure Setting)
3. Open a qualified app (has sound, and doesn't prevent the phone from sleep, like angry bird, Cytus, etc)
4. Wait for screen off
5. Note whether the sound continues for 30s after screen off.